# Git hooks: Change commit message depending from diff of specific files

Tags: git, diff, githooks

If specific files changed(list of path to files are stored in a file), then need to append some text to commit message, like `New OSB config needed` and of course commit it. What hook I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a commit once it's made (because it is stored by its object ID, which is a checksum of its contents, so that if you attempt to change anything you get a new, different object ID).  This means you must use a hook that runs before the commit is made.  So, consulting [the githooks documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), we find three hooks run before making a commit (and one after, which is too late):

- `pre-commit`
- `prepare-commit-msg`
- `commit-msg`

The first one runs too *early*, before the commit message exists in any form.  That leaves only two possibilities: before the commit message is given to you to edit (`prepare-commit-msg`), or after you have finished editing it but before it gets used as part of the commit creation (`commit-msg`).

Choose which you prefer, noting the `--no-verify` point as well.  In general I find hooks that do stuff I *can't* see to be obnoxious (which for me would push me towards the "prepare" hook), but presumably this hook will be your own creation, used only by you, so you can set it up however you prefer.

Comment: I think about commit-msg, because it is using commit message template that is being validated on inputted text. I will append "config needed" text before the validation of the commit message. Thank you)